# How to retrieve string stored inside a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable `params` inside a function `someFunction()`,

```
function someFunction() {
  var params = ""
  params += "type=" + type + "&intro=" + intro + "&val=" + val; // then I add a value on params
  console.log(params.val); // now, how can i do this?
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't access it like that...

Comment: Methods you have used are used to access the property of the object by mentioning the key. You have string as an input not `object`

Comment: "params" variable consist of the string as value.To get the value of "val " use Slice, Substring, or Substr function.

Comment: @RayonDabre The problem is not that `params` is a string, instead of an object, the problem is that property access works on the prototype chain, not on inner contents of a string. That means, `params["val"]` would access the property `val` from `params`, but it’s not an existing property in the given example, it’s just part of the content of the string. `params["split"]`, however, _works_, because `split` is a property on `String.prototype`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the URL parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter)

Comment: @Xufox, Ooh yes! Never looked at it that way..

Comment: @Xufox, the one you are referring is getting the value of url parameter which is completely different approach to mine, which is to access it in another function

Comment: @HardSpocker, Can you show us how you are accessing `anotherFunction` and which arguments are being passed ?

Comment: @HardSpocker, You are overriding `params`, use different variable name..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to write your custom function.
Here what I have tried.

```
window.onload = function() {

  var params = "";
  var type = "types";
  var intro = "int";
  var val = "values";

  params += "type=" + type + "&intro=" + intro + "&val=" + val;

  var convertToObject = function(strParams) {

    var objQueryString = {};
    var arrParam = strParams.split('&');
    console.log(arrParam)

    arrParam.forEach(function(value, key) {

      var arrKyValue = value.split('=');
      objQueryString[arrKyValue[0]] = arrKyValue[1];

    })

    return objQueryString;
  }

  objParams = convertToObject(params);

  console.log(objParams.val, objParams["val"])

}
```

Here is [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ipTU839lqhcY9nrvc32F?p=preview)

Comment: I thank all of you for helping me and giving me answers, but this one gave me solution so I need to put a check here. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `params` variable is just a `string`. What you are trying to do is access it like an `object`.

A better solution would be:

```
// Create an object
var params = {};

// Create the properties
params.type = "some type";
params.val = "some value";
params.intro = "some intro";

// Alternatively
var params = {
    type: "some type",
    val: "some value",
    intro: "some intro"
};

// Function that does something with your params
function doSomething(input) {
    console.log(input.val);
}

// Function that converts your object to a query string
function toQueryString(input) {
    var keyValuePairs = [];
    for (var key in input) {
        if (input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            keyValuePairs.push(encodeURI(key) + "=" + encodeURI(input[key]));
        }
    }
    return keyValuePairs.join("&");
}

doSomething(params);
console.log(toQueryString(params));
```

Outputs

> some value
>
> type=some%20type&val=some%20value&intro=some%20intro

As a side note, it is generally a bad idea to use words that can be potentially a keyword in your code or in the future (IE: `params`). A better name would be one that is informative, such as `welcomeMessage`, `introduction` or `employee` (Based off the 3 values you listed)

Answer (score 2):

When it's a string, it's a string. You could parse it to get values based on known format, but there is no way of referencing something *inside* of the string.

Therefore, it's better to store params in the object for later use and create a string only when you need it, based on that object.

So, it could be like this:

```
var params = {
  val: val,
  type: type,
  intro: intro
};
```

then, `params.val` will be accessible. When you'll need a string, you'd do `var string = "type=" + params.type + "&intro=" + params.intro + "&val=" + params.val;`

Answer (score 0):

`var params = ""` is not a function, its a statement. A function in JS is created by using `function(params) = {}` or in ES6 you can use `=>`. When you use `+=` on a sting you are saying "take whatever string is already in params and add on to it what Im about to tell you." After your statement is evaluated you have a new string. Although strings can be accessed like arrays e.g. `x = 'hello'` and then `x[0]` would return 'h' where 0 refers to the character at the index of the string. You are trying to use dot notation which is used for JS object literals e.g. `x = {prop1: 200, prop2: 300}` then `x.prop1` would return 200. Or using the array syntax you would do `x[prop1]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way, check demo - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/u73524po/):

```
var value = false, temp;
params.split('&').forEach( function(item) {
      temp = item.split('=');
        if(temp[0] === 'val') {
            value = temp[1];
        }
})

console.log(value);
```